# R: running t-test on one column of a dataframe versus all others

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the basic form:

```
> head(raw.data)

       NAC     cOF3     APir       Pu       Tu     V2.3     mOF3     DGpf
1 6.314770 6.181188 6.708971 6.052134 6.546938 6.079848 6.640716 6.263770
2 8.825595 8.740217 9.532026 8.919598 8.776969 8.843287 8.631505 9.053732
3 5.518933 5.982044 5.632379 5.712680 5.655525 5.580141 5.750969 6.119935
4 6.063098 6.700194 6.255736 5.124315 6.133631 5.891009 6.070467 6.062815
5 8.931570 9.048621 9.258875 8.681762 8.680993 9.040971 8.785271 9.122226
6 5.694149 5.356218 5.608698 5.894171 5.629965 5.759247 5.929289 6.092337
```

I would like to perform t-tests of each column versus all **other** columns and save the subsequent p-values to a variable in some variation of the following:

```
#run tests
test.result = mapply(t.test, one.column, other.columns)
#store p-values
p.values = stack(mapply(function(x, y) 
     +     t.test(x,y)$p.value, one.column, other.columns))
```

Or would aov() be a better option for such an analysis? In any case, I would like to know how to streamline doing it using t-tests.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

Read in the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text='NAC     cOF3     APir       Pu       Tu     V2.3     mOF3     DGpf
1 6.314770 6.181188 6.708971 6.052134 6.546938 6.079848 6.640716 6.263770
2 8.825595 8.740217 9.532026 8.919598 8.776969 8.843287 8.631505 9.053732
3 5.518933 5.982044 5.632379 5.712680 5.655525 5.580141 5.750969 6.119935
4 6.063098 6.700194 6.255736 5.124315 6.133631 5.891009 6.070467 6.062815
5 8.931570 9.048621 9.258875 8.681762 8.680993 9.040971 8.785271 9.122226
6 5.694149 5.356218 5.608698 5.894171 5.629965 5.759247 5.929289 6.092337')
```

Get all possible pairwise combinations:

```
com <- combn(colnames(dat), 2)
```

Get the p-values

```
p <- apply(com, 2, function(x) t.test(dat[,x[1]], dat[,x[2]])$p.val)
```

Put into a data frame:

```
data.frame(comparison = paste(com[1,], com[2,], sep = ' vs. '), p.value = p)
```

An even better solution is to use melt from the rehape package and pairwise.t.test:

```
library(reshape)
with(melt(dat), pairwise.t.test(value, variable, p.adjust.method = 'none'))
```

If you want to pair just the first with all other columns, you can also use this:

```
x <- sapply(dat[,-1], function(x) t.test(x, dat[,1])$p.value)
data.frame(variable = names(x), p.value = as.numeric(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I have tried it and it works great. However, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't just pair columns 1 to 1, but 1 **to the rest** for each and every possible column. In other words, column 1 vs. columns 2-n, column 2 vs. 1,3-n, etc.

Comment: I have now edited my posting and provide another solution at the end. I hope this helps.